# Insertar <ul> después de cada 3 elementos PHP

Tags: php, html5

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<li class='product col-md-3 col-sm-4'><div class='product-thumb-wrap'><div class='product-thumb'><a href='$row[link]'><img src='$row[imagen]' alt=''></a><a href='$row[link]' class='product-add-cart'><span class='pull-left'>Ver Más</span><i class='pull-right fa fa-shopping-cart'></i></a></div></div><div class='product-info'><a><h3 class='dark-color fw-600'>$row[title]</h3></a><div class='product-cate'><a>Código:</a> <a>$row[codigo]</a></div></div></li>";

    $cars  = array($row[link],$row[imagen],$row[title],$row[codigo]);
    $longitud = count($cars);
//  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('$longitud')</script>";
    for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++)
    {
        $cars[$i];
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('$cars[$i]')</script>";
    }
//  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('$cars')</script>";
}
```

El problema es de que estoy intentando que mis elementos HTML creados dinamicamente desde un ARRAY PHP se inserten dentro de un `<ul>` después de cada 3

Comment: while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
         {
          echo "<li class='product col-md-3 col-sm-4'><div class='product-thumb-wrap'><div class='product-thumb'><a href='$row[link]'><img src='$row[imagen]' alt=''></a><a href='$row[link]' class='product-add-cart'><span class='pull-left'>Ver Más</span><i class='pull-right fa fa-shopping-cart'></i></a></div></div><div class='product-info'><a><h3 class='dark-color fw-600'>$row[title]</h3></a><div class='product-cate'><a>Código:</a> <a>$row[codigo]</a></div></div></li>";

Comment: Podrias explicarte un poco mejor?

Comment: claro @LeonardoCabré, desde un array php estoy trayendo resultados, como lo son: link, imagen, titulo, etc, ahora bien todo esto lo coloco dentro de un <li>, pero quiero que cada 3 <li> se puedan meter dentro de un <ul>

Comment: Añade un ejemplo de la estructura de como quieres que quede. no me queda claro del todo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creas un contador y lo usas para ver cuando insertar la etiqueta

```
$counter = 0; $rep = 3;
echo "<ul>"; //primera
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $counter++; 
   if ($counter == $rep) { echo "</ul><ul>"; $counter= 0; }

        echo "<li class='product col-md-3 col-sm-4'><div class='product-thumb-wrap'><div class='product-thumb'><a href='$row[link]'><img src='$row[imagen]' alt=''></a><a href='$row[link]' class='product-add-cart'><span class='pull-left'>Ver Más</span><i class='pull-right fa fa-shopping-cart'></i></a></div></div><div class='product-info'><a><h3 class='dark-color fw-600'>$row[title]</h3></a><div class='product-cate'><a>Código:</a> <a>$row[codigo]</a></div></div></li>";

        $cars  = array($row[link],$row[imagen],$row[title],$row[codigo]);
        $longitud = count($cars);
    //  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('$longitud')</script>";
        for($i=0; $i<$longitud; $i++)
        {
            $cars[$i];
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('$cars[$i]')</script>";
        }
    //  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>console.log('$cars')</script>";
    }
echo "</ul>"; //última
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos problemas que solucionar de antemano.

**Primero: estás usando el antiguo conector `mysql` que está descontinuado**. Utiliza PDO o mysqli. Intercambiar uno por otro es trivial.

el cambio para usar mysqli, es tan sencillo como tomar la parte donde dice:

```
$conexion =  mysql_connect('localhost', 'usuario_mysql', 'contraseña_mysql');
$result = mysql_query($consulta, $conexion);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 ...
}
```

Y reemplazarlo con:

```
$conexion =  mysqli_connect('localhost', 'usuario_mysql', 'contraseña_mysql');

$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   ...
}
```

El ejemplo que te puse es el camino de migración más corto, pero mysqli te permite trabajar orientado a objetos y eso te cambiará la vida.

**Segundo: Mal uso de los nombres de llaves**

Cuando usas:

```
$cars  = array($row[link],$row[imagen],$row[title],$row[codigo]);
```

Debieras usar las propiedades entrecomilladas (ej `$row['link']`). No hacerlo provoca que PHP lo considere una constante. Pero la constante `link` no está definida (se gatilla un error por debajo, pero dependiendo del nivel de errores que estés logueando, pasa desapercibido para ti) así que PHP asume que la constante `link` tiene el valor `"link"`.

Lo mismo ocurre cuando interpolas `$row[link]` dentro de tu HTML.

Dicho esto, yo lo solucionaría con:

```
$contador = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   if($contador % 3 === 0 ) {
      echo '<ul>';
   }
   echo '<li>...</li>';

   if($contador % 3 === 2 ) {
      echo '</ul>';
   }
   $contador++;
}
if ($contador % 3) {
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Estoy usando el operador `modulo` para obtener el resto de la división `$contador/3` que puede tener los valores 0, 1 y 2.

- Si el modulo vale 0, abro un `<ul>` antes de imprimir el `<li>`
- Si el modulo vale 2, cierro con un `</ul>` después del `<li>`.
- Al terminar el bucle, puede que mi lista no sea múltiplo de 3 y no haya cerrado el `<ul>` que quedó abierto. Hago una comprobación para cerrar con un `</ul>` en ese caso.

**Una sugerencia:**

El html de tu elemento `<li>` está muy sucio y su estructura es difícil de comprender. Sería mucho más eficiente declararlo como una plantilla [NOWDOC](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) y luego usar `printf`:

Para definir la plantilla (antes del bucle, o antes de la consulta incluso):

```
$plantilla = <<<'EOD'
<li class="product col-md-3 col-sm-4">
    <div class="product-thumb-wrap">
        <div class="product-thumb">
            <a href="%1$s"><img src="%2$s" alt=""></a>
            <a href="%1$s" class="product-add-cart">
                <span class="pull-left">Ver Más</span>
                <i class="pull-right fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-info">
        <a><h3 class="dark-color fw-600">%3$s</h3></a>
        <div class="product-cate">
            <a>Código:</a>
            <a>%4$s</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
EOD;
```

Para usarla:

```
$contador = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   if($contador % 3 === 0 ) {
      echo '<ul>';
   }

   printf($plantilla, $row['link'], $row['imagen'], $row['title'], $row['codigo']);

   if($contador % 3 === 2 ) {
      echo '</ul>';
   }
   $contador++;
}
if ($contador % 3) {
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

[Te dejo un fiddle funcionando](https://www.tehplayground.com/Aqd6uiv3W9Tis4yN), aunque utiliza un array asociativo en vez de una consulta para efectos del ejemplo

(Acá hay [otro fiddle](https://eval.in/1035670) que muestra la salida en HTML, gentileza de https://eval.in).